# Pass shell variables as arguments to PHP script

Tags: php, shell

I want to pass shell variables to a PHP script.  This is my attempt:

```
var1=`echo name_16`
var2=`echo /home/place/end/name_16`
php script.php ${var1} ${var2}
```

These variables contain special characters [`)(*&^%$#@!~<>_`] but no hyphens.

**I am running PHP 4.3.9 cgi.**

I attempt to pick up the variables in my PHP script thus:

```
    $fish = $argv[1];
    $sticks = $argv[2];
```

These variables come up as null.  I've tried `var_dump($argv);` and this returns null as well.
Am I passing these parameters correctly or am I missing something here?

Comment: From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803025/pass-parameters-to-php-with-shell

Try `$_SERVER['argv']`

Comment: Exactly what do your parameters look like? Examples? I did a quick check with a simple alphabetic param and had no problem.

Comment: Post an actual example of how you're calling this script with the variables

Comment: the example is exactly how I am calling the script from within a .sh script.

Comment: So you're defining your variables after you call script.php?

Comment: There is no need for the `echo` or back-ticks; you could perfectly well assign: `var1="name_16"` and `var2="/home/place/end/name_16"`, and even the double quotes aren't 100% necessary in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to add this as a comment, but need the formatting ability of an answer to respond.

There's something else wrong with the code. A basic test of arguments shows that the variables should work.

Contents of `foo.php`:

```
<?php
    print "$argv[1]\n$argv[2]\n" ;

    $x = $argv[1];
    $y = $argv[2];

    print "$x\n$y\n";
?>
```

Then the setup:

```
$ var1=`echo name_16`
$ var2=`echo /home/place/end/name_16`
```

And execution:

```
$ php foo.php ${var1} ${var2}
name_16
/home/place/end/name_16
name_16
/home/place/end/name_16
$
```

So the problem is not reproducible using the information provided. The above is run with **`PHP 5.2.6 (cli) (built: May  8 2008 08:53:44)`**, so it is, perhaps, a difference in version behavior.

Comment: i figured it would be the version.  possibly that I don't have access to cli.

Comment: @eddiecubed could you try the same simple test that I did above and see what happens, just to be sure we're apples-to-apples?

Comment: I get nulls for output.  The problem here is the version.  The variable register_argc_argv is set to false.  Which means the argv never gets built.  So i need to look into using a different way of sending these variables over.

Comment: @eddiecubed thanks for trying the specific experiment; I agree with your conclusion.

Comment: thanks for being helpful.  I decided to just go with writing the variables to a text file in sh and then read the file within php.  This worked.

Answer (score 0):

just use `$argv`, its an array of arguments and quotes around special args.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

test.php:

```
<?php
  print_r($argv);
?>


>HHH="&^%$#@"
> php test.php hello args $HHH
```

output:

```
Array
(
[0] => test.php
[1] => hello
[2] => args
[3] => &^%$#@

)
```

Comment: I've tried this and it comes up with nothing.  I've tried var_dump and I come up with null.

Comment: i just ran it and it worked. did you put quotes around the special args?

Comment: I've tried your test verbatim and I get empty output.